# How can I redirect to a view when click an html Dropdown list in mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a medical application. I have dropdownlist includes patient names. How can I redirect to a view which shows the vital signs of selected patient when click a dropdown list. I used entity framework to bind data to dropdownlist.

```
        this is what I did.


        //Controller

        public ViewResult PatientLIstView()
    {
        PatientListdbEntities dbcontext = new PatientListdbEntities();
        var getPatientlist = dbcontext.Patient_Reg.ToList();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(getPatientlist, "Preg_id", "P_Name");
        ViewBag.patients = list;

        return View();
    }

    // this is the view


    @{
ViewBag.Title = "PatientLIstView";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }



   <div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">
      <table align="center" style="margin-top:8%;margin-left:18%">

        <tr>
        <td>Patient List</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("paients1", ViewBag.patients as SelectList, 
  "---select---")</td></tr>
    </table>
   @*@Html.DropDownList("paients1", ViewBag.patients as SelectList, "---
    select---", new { style = "height: 100px;" })*@

     </div>
  </div>
```

now I have the patient list. How can get the dropdown selected value in controller so that I can show the respective patient information in another view?

Comment: You need javascript to respond to client side events (or just submit a the form to a method which redirects to the page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Line, this calls to a other methode in your controller who search and show your the patient id Info.

```
@Html.DropDownList(@Html.ActionLink("Edit", actionname, controllername, new { Id = Patient }), ViewBag.patients as SelectList, 
"---select---")'
```

let me know if you have more problems.

Comment: Shall i give "actionname" and "controllername" as string if not tell how to do that and  what do u mean by "new { Id = Patient }". I am beginner to MVC . thats why I have asking like this.

Comment: Do you use a database?

Comment: yes. I am using Entity framework to bind dropdowm.   "Preg_id" is the value of dropdown and  "P_Name" is the text to be displayed.

Comment: Oke, you can make a new page, and call this PatientInfo. now you can set this line instead of yours. @Html.DropDownList(@Html.ActionLink("PatientName", "PatientInfo", "controllerclass", new { Id = Preg_id}), ViewBag.patients as SelectList, 
"---select---")'

Comment: its doesn't work . shows  Preg_id does't exists in the current context

Comment: And if you put there the same code as you put in your value of the dropdown item?

Comment: oo, In my project i does this methode. i am sorry